# Xml parsing with Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, pattern-recognition

I got a school project to read a xml code with Matlab. 
The example of my xml code is like this :

```
-<event probability="0.9" gravity="0.9" complexity="0.9" name="Cloud Fire" id="cloud_fire">
-<predicates>
<predicate>(fire ?c - cloud)</predicate>
</predicates>
</event>
```

Is there exist an easy way to read these patterns? Or do I have to make my own code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `xmlread`?

Comment: Yes but it gave me [#document: null]. I don't know how this function works actually.

Comment: Is this a file you wrote by yourself? Are you sure all the parts is included for this to be a properly formatted xml file? Further, the function returns a Document Object Model (DOM). This may for example mean that the xml file may not be viewable in the command window as other matlab variables. Try to do `xmlwrite(myLoadedFileVariable)`. This should print the xml code in matlab if the xml file were properly formatted.

Comment: Yes, it printed exactly the same code. So is this means my code is in the good format? What do you think might be wrong then?

Comment: Why would anything be wrong? Do you get an error? Would you like to explain the problem you have?

Comment: I am sorry. I got the [#document: null], so i think it is some kind of error. I don't really know how i can use the xmlread. What am i supposed to do after that?

Comment: The documentation for `xlsread` contains some example. Use `getDocumentElement` to get the root document node and `getChildNodes` to explore the structure.

Comment: As I said, you uses a DOM model. This is a node tree with _methods_ to add and remove nodes, search the tree,... I think that this is some java API implemented by matlab. You should read up on this. Example on good pages, [mathworks blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/09/13/simple-xml-node-creation/), [xmlread](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html), make sure to follow the links from xmlread. Further, normally xml version and encoding is included in the xml file, eg <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>. I think that is optional though.

Comment: Sorry, I think my point got lost in the [last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385938/xml-parsing-with-matlab?noredirect=1#comment46952402_29385938). What I meant was that [#document: null] is expected. If you read the links you will see how to access the nodes. I can say that you are not the only one who have been confused by this in the beginning though.

Comment: Thank you @patrik, I think I am starting to understand how it works now. You have helped me a lot.